# Zend_Search_Lucene Limiting the Result Set

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

Is there a way to limit the Result Set by the best **N** results? If I use `Zend_Search_lucene::setResultSetLimit(10)` I will only get any 10 results and not the 10 best results according to my sorting declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can't use

```
Zend_Search_lucene::setResultSetLimit(N)
```

because it gives you just the first N elements.

> **Limiting the Result Set**
>
> The most computationally expensive
>   part of searching is score
>   calculation. It may take several
>   seconds for large result sets (tens of
>   thousands of hits).
>
> Zend_Search_Lucene gives the
>   possibility to limit result set size
>   with getResultSetLimit() and
>   setResultSetLimit() methods:

```
  $currentResultSetLimit = Zend_Search_Lucene::getResultSetLimit();  
  Zend_Search_Lucene::setResultSetLimit($newLimit);
```

> The default value of 0 means 'no
>   limit'.
>
> It doesn't give the 'best N' results,
>   but only the 'first N'.

How can you search for just 10 results and define them as best? You must search the entire index to determine the best results.

By default, the search results are ordered by score. Have a look at the documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html

*By the way, whatever you are doing with zend lucene, think about using an other search engine like [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html). I use it in many projects and I recommend to use it. It is much faster and better to manage. To use it in a zend framework project you have to use a [solr php client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/).*

Comment: Yes you must search the entire index, but there is no reason to return the entire index once you have sorted them. For instance in standard SQL the query `SELECT * FROM table ORDERBY field ASC LIMIT 10` orders the entire index, but it then only returns the first 10 records from the sorted index.